# Computing the presentation of a morphism of a $k$-algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

To compute the Kahler differentials of a ring map $A\to B$, one writes $B = A[\{x_i\}]/(\{f_j\})$ and then we find $\Omega_{B/A} = \bigoplus Bdx_i/\sum Bdf_j$.

This raises the question (for me), how can I find the presentation $B = A[x_i]/(f_j)$ in general? Here's a simple example.

Consider the normalization of the cuspidal cubic $\mathbb A^1 = \operatorname{Spec}k[t]\to X = \operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ given by $x\mapsto t^3,y\mapsto t^2$.

To compute $\Omega_{\mathbb A^1/X}$, I want to write $k[t]$ as $(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3))[u_i]/(g_i)$ and compute the differentials as above. Apparently, the answer is $k[t]dt/(tdt)$.

How can I do this systematically? I'm happy to see an answer specific to morphisms of affine $k$-varieties, but more generality is great too.

Comment: Generally finding presentations of an $A$-algebra which is known to be finitely presented can be difficult, but most examples one works with have some properties which makes it easier. In the example you gave, the affine line is the normalization of the cuspidal cubic which has a particularly nice form in this case.

Comment: Thanks K02. Could show me how to calculate the presentation for this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP asked for a specific example so this is to explain the answer given in the post. This turned out to be longer than a comment so I'm posting it here instead.

First off, let me imagine $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)\cong k[t^2,t^3]$. Then $k[t^2,t^3]\to k[t]$ gives the map from the affine line to the cuspidal cubic. To write $k[t]$ as a $k[t^2,t^3]$ algebra, we write $B:=k[t]=k[t^2,t^3][u]/(u^2-t^2,u^3-t^3)$. Then $d(u^2-t^2)=2udu$ and $d(u^3-t^3)=3u^2du$. The reason $d(t^2)=d(t^3)=0$ is because $t^2,t^3\in k[t^2,t^3]=:A$ which are killed off.

The relations $2udu=0$ and $3u^2du=0$ imply that we only need a single relation: $udu=0$. So we see that viewing $u$ as the variable $t$, we have $\Omega_{B/A}=Bdu/(udu)=k[t]dt/(tdt)$ as in OP's post.

Second off, is OP's question about finding the presentations in general, there are computer programs designed for this such as [Macaulay2's presentation(module)](https://macaulay2.com/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_presentation_lp__Module_rp.html) function. Generally, the examples one computes are when $\Omega_{B/A}$ comes from $A$-algebra morphisms $A\to B$ associated to $\operatorname{Spec}(B)\to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ being closed immersions, open immersions, etale, and so on. Another method to circumvent the computation of presentations is to use the following.

> First Fundamental Exact Sequence (Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory Theorem 25.1): For $k\to A\to B$ ring homorphisms, there is an exact sequence $$\Omega_{A/k}\otimes_AB\to^\alpha\Omega_{B/k}\to \Omega_{B/A}\to 0.$$
> The map $\alpha$ being $d_{A/k}a\otimes b\to b(d_{B/k}a)$ and the send map sending $d_{B/k}b\to d_{B/A}b$. Here, the subscripts indicates which module of differentials I am in. *Furthermore*, if there are some smoothness hypotheses, then this is actually left exact.

Applied to the example, we would get $k[t^2,t^3]dt^2\oplus k[t^2,t^3]dt^3\otimes_A k[t]\to k[t]dt\to \Omega_{B/A}\to 0$. The definition of the first map says the image is generated by the relations $d(t^2)=2tdt$
and $d(t^3)=3t^2dt$. So the image, a $B$-submodule, is generated by $tdt$.

Personally, I find Matsumura's presentation in Chapter 25 *Derivations and Differentials* to be really good so if you want more practice and details, this is where I would start.

Comment: This is very helpful K02, thanks so much! I'll check out Matsumura's book per your suggestion. BTW did you use Macaulay2 to get your presentation for $k[t]$ over $k[t^2,t^3]$, or did you have a method to get this presentation? I suppose in hindsight it's easy to see you need "$t$" in your ring, so map $u$ to $t$ and then have $u^2-t^2$ and $u^3-t^3$ in the kernel; do you then prove "by hand" that this is the whole kernel?

Comment: @Nico I did not use Macaulay2, I just used the relations I saw it must have. Technically you should check that you have the right kernel, but I did not write it for sake of time.